# How to call a mousedown event when a menu item is clicked?

Tags: c#, menuitem

I am making a project on image processing in c# and I have a picturebox in my form and menu strip having various options(operations) that can be applied on an image (such as blur,sepia,contrast etc.). I was thinking of implementing a cropping control and I have included it as menu item.

What I want is whenever I click crop option from menustrip it fires mousedown,mouse move and mouse up events of the picturebox so that cropping can be performed.

Here is the code for cropping in this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images

The problem is how to implement cropping controls only when menu item is clicked. The code on above link in triggered whenever user clicks picturebox and not when someone clicks a menu item or say a button per se.

Thanks in advance for help....

Comment: Ensure the menu item is checkonclick and test its checked property before doing anything in your mousexyz handlers.

Answer (score -1):

You should abstract the cropping code away from the event handlers and into some image manipulation class that also contains the image. Then you can wire your mousemove events into the specific crop calls, like:

```
public void MouseMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SomeImage.Crop(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

However when you want the click handler to do the cropping, to what coordinates will you crop? You'll have to decide that, and then implement it in your menu click handler:

```
public void CropMenuClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: determine someX and someY
    SomeImage.Crop(someX, someY);
}
```